# Xml export with magento with french characters

Tags: xml, excel, magento, export

Here my problem :

I use a Magento , i try to export products in xml format cause i have to work on later. The export works correctly nor problem.

My problem is when i want to edit in Microsoft Excel my datas from the XML file all french caracters (é,è,à,ù,...) are replaced with a  Ã© for example.

So my DB is completly modified when there are french diacritics.

Im lost and i dont know how keep my file safe. When i open my xml in notepad ++ the é,è,à are not replaced, but i cant do anything from notepad++. Importing in EXcel or something like excel is mandatory for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an magento error. Your excel didnt support french character. So,

To resolve this issue, please do the following:

```
Save the Excel file as a CSV file.
Open the CSV file generated by Excel using another software which can create UTF-8 compliant CSV files. On Windows computers - the easiest way to do this is as follows:
    Open the file using Notepad.
    Click "File > Save As".
    In the dialog window that appears - select "UTF-8" from the "Encoding" field. Then click "Save".
That's all! Just use this new CSV file within the Import Wizard in Accompa.
```

or follow this link ***[click me](http://www.accompa.com/kb/answer.html?answer_id=262)***